# What is the difference between QAndroidJniObject::callMethod() and QAndroidJniObject::callObjectMethod()?

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt5, qtandroidextras

I noticed that the Qt documentation offers two methods for calling android native methods but I can't figure out when to use `QAndroidJniObject::callMethod` and when to use `QAndroidJniObject::callObjectMethod`. What is the rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference is that `QAndroidJniObject::callMethod` returns a primitive data type like `jint` or `jbyte` but `QAndroidJniObject::callObjectMethod` returns an object of type `QAndroidJniObject`.

Using which one all depends on your needs and the return type of the function you want to call. If your function returns an object type like `jobject`, `jstring`, `jarray`,... then you should definitely use `QAndroidJniObject::callObjectMethod`. Otherwise you can use either of the two.